# See if previous command is still running in PyCharm IPython console?

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

Is there any way to see if a command is currently being executed in the PyCharm console?

Running an interactive python session in the terminal, after executing a command, the prompt disappears until execution has finished. For example when I call `time.sleep(5)`, it takes 5 seconds until the `>>>` appears again, so I know the command is still being executed.

Running an IPython console in PyCharm the prompt never disappears. Only when I start typing again I get a message "Previous command is still running". This way it's hard to see when a command has finished without constantly "probing" the prompt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This is resolved in the latest builds of PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15727)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14182196)

Comment: @sushildlh The essential parts of the link are already in the answer -- the issue described by the OP is resolved in the latest build of the software. There is nothing more to say on the matter.

Comment: Can you explain what happens in the latest build? Reading the bug report doesn't really indicate what happens -- a screenshot is included but that's using a different console, not the IPython one. There's no comment or screenshot describing the fix, it's just the status that says that.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the best way to do when using IPython is to the `%time` magic command whenever you need to run a long command. For details, see https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-time

Usage:

```
In[1]: %time time.sleep(5)
Wall time: 5 s
```

The second line will appear when the code finishes. This also has the added bonus of telling you how long execution took.

Note: Don't accidentally confuse it with the `%timeit` command which will run your code several times